# PHP Dropdown pulling information from SQL database

Tags: php, forms, input, dql

I'm trying to create a drop down with all my currencies, at the moment the values are 1, 2 & 3. I need the values of the drop down to stay as the number, but want the option text to say GBP, EUR and USD instead. I have this code:

```
<select class='dc_input' name='currency' id ='currency'>
    <?php

    $sql="SELECT l.currency
                    FROM locations l
                    GROUP BY l.currency";

        $sites = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sites)) {
            echo '<option value="' .$row['currency']. '"' .$selected. '>  </option>';
        }
    ?>

</select>
```

This works, I just don't know what to put in to make it change for each one.

Comment: what do you mean with `what to put in to make it change for each one.`?

Comment: Do you have the text in the table? If yes, what is the field name?

Comment: No i don't have text in the table, just numbers, i want to define the text in the code.

Comment: So look at @Eray answer. He defines an array based on values you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$currencies = array('', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'USD');
?>
<select class='dc_input' name='currency' id ='currency'>
    <?php

    $sql="SELECT l.currency
                    FROM locations l
                    GROUP BY l.currency";

        $sites = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sites)) {
            $index = $row['currency'];
            echo '<option value="' .$index. '"' .$selected. '> '.$currencies[$index].' </option>';
        }
    ?>

</select>
```

Also you can store currency ID's and currency name's on database . If you start supporting more than 3 currencies, it will be more easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not selecting the number from your database.  Once you do, put the text in between the opening/closing tag, and leave the numeric value in the value attribute.

```
echo '<option value="', htmlspecialchars($row['id']), '">',
     htmlspecialchars($row['currency']), '</option>';
```

Comment: `$row['currency']` always equals 1,2 or 3. I need to keep that as the value, and the text needs to change depending on the number. so if it equals 1, the text should be GBP etc.

Comment: there isn't a field with the text in it

Comment: @CarlaDessi, Add an array to your project containing the mapping of currency to value.  Then use something like `$currencyMap[$row['currency']]`.